# ArrayAdapter with string array and Jsoup

Tags: android, json, parsing, jsoup, android-arrayadapter

I am able to extract the href elements from a page and store the results into a string array. Then display it inside a TextView. The problem comes if I try to display to a ListView. I don't know how to work with ArrayAdapters in this case. This is my working code that displays into a TextView.

```
package com.example.jsouptestarray;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import com.example.jsouptestarray.R;


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView text;
    ListView list; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new MyTask().execute();  
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

        ArrayList<String> arr_linkText=new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {

             Document doc;
             String linkText = ""; 

             try {
                 doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/").get();
                 Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
                 for (Element el : links) { 
                     linkText = el.attr("href");
                     arr_linkText.add(linkText); // add value to ArrayList
                 }
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

             return arr_linkText;     //<< retrun ArrayList from here
        } 


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {        

            // get all value from result to display in TextView
            for (String temp_result : result) {
                 System.out.println("links :: "+temp_result);
                 text = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView2);
                 text.append(temp_result + "\n" + "\n");
                 text.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is my attempt with the ListView, but I get an error and I don't understand how to fix it.

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, temp_result);

// Assign adapter to ListView
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is a screenshot of the error

[image]

I hope someone can help me fix it, and I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fourth element of the constructor is excess in your case. It can be used to set data at once, you should see [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E%29).
Try this:

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, 
                             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                             android.R.id.text1);

for (String temp_result : result)
{
   adapter.add(temp_result);
}

// Assign adapter to ListView
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: updated the answer, I forgot about `MainActivity.this` as mentioned in another comment

Answer (score 2):

Replace `this` with `MainActivity.this`. When you're inside the AsyncTask, `this` refers to the AsyncTask instance, which can't be passed to the constructor (different, unrelated, incompatible classes)

So you need to call an Activity as the argument and since your AsyncTask is part of an Activity, you can explictly reference the Activity instance with `ClassName.this`.

Comment: Combine our answers, take out one argument and use `MainActivity.this`